# Postman REST API automation without duplicating tests

Tags: postman

I have 8 requests and I want to run the first three before running each of the other requests. E.g.

```
1st collection: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4
2nd collection: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 5
3rd collection: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 6
4th collection: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 7
5th collection: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 8
```

Currently I've duplicated the first three requests for each of the other requests, but this makes changing them time consuming.

Is there a way to use the Postman Runner to execute the above without duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have a a collection with all your tests and use the setNextRequest feature (refer to http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/). With that, I guess you could manage to select request 4 at the first iteration, request 5 at the next, etc. conditioning setNextRequest with an incrementing global variable.

Alexandre